# How long can a notification be kept for (permanently)?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-notification-bar, android-background

I have a service with `startForeground(requestCode, notification);` and have it set so that `setOngoing(true)` so the user cannot remove notification. How long does this notification stay alive for? Will it stay alive forever (until user restarts phone)?

I have noticed that if I start the service and let the phone sit idle for a few hours that the notification is still present but becomes unresponsive to the button click service methods. Is this the case because I do not have a partial wake lock?

This notification is for controlling android settings like brightness setting which is why I need the notification running always.

Would it be better to use a normal notification with setOngoing(true) and then start a service which would call a method for each button that is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems to keep the service/notification running is to use a repeating alarm:

```
public void startAlarm(){
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 200*1000, alarmIntent);
}
```

I am not certain of the optimum frequency for resetting the alarm, but I have set it to a few minutes for now. Every few minutes my service is started/resumed.

Answer (score 1):

Notification will be kept before rebooting phone, I learn it from own experience :).

After some time your service is killed by the system to obtain more memory, thats why notification became unresponsive.

If you want service run always, it is better to return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) from  onStartCommand(). It will be automatically restarted after killing.

I don't know is using of normal notification better, try START_STICKY first.